# Pell's type equation in sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have an another observation on concatenation in sum. For instance, take $12^2 + 33^2 = 1233$. Find as many such pairs (x, y) with $x^2 + y^2 = xy\,$(here xy is concatenation)is possible. Also, discuss how this is happening and is there any connection between this kind of problem and pell's equations?
I got $10^2 + 1^2 = 101$;
$0^2 + 1^2 = 01$;
$88^2 + 33^2 = 8833$;
$12^2 + 33^2 = 1233$;
such pairs.

Comment: This is one of a number of questions you have asked on squares and concatenation. What I am wondering is where these questions are coming from, or whether they are simply random examples. In these days of computers it is quite easy to find examples of things like this, if they exist and are not too big (I sometimes use a spreadsheet even). It is much harder to bring mathematical coherence, or to see why there should be a connection with Pell's equation. At the moment I'm struggling to see how this is a clear enough question to have a useful answer.

Comment: @Mark Bennet! I am working on trail and eroor method to find some concatenation numbers. I attended to Prof. Gandhi lectures at India. Then I am more existed to learn and create such pairs by my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to $x^2 + y^2 = 10^n x + y$ with size constraints on $y$ (preferably $10^{n-1} \le y < 10^n$, though we will shortly see that the right-hand inequality is superfluous).

Completing the square gives $(2x - 10^n)^2 + (2y - 1)^2 = 10^{2n} + 1$, so we are looking for a way to write $10^{2n}+1$ as the sum of two squares $A^2+B^2$, where $A = 2x-10^n$ is even and $B=2y-1$ is odd.  Since clearly $B \le 10^n$, we needn't worry about $y$ being too large, but we'd like $B \ge \tfrac15\cdot10^n - 1$ so that $y$ doesn't need to be zero-padded before concatenation (otherwise we could use the trivial solution $A=10^n$, $B=1$ giving $x=10^n$, $y=1$).

A simple way to construct solutions is to choose $n$ in certain congruence classes so that $10^{2n}+1$ has a particular prime factor that yields a non-trivial decomposition as the sum of two squares.  For instance if $n = 16k+12$ we have $10^n \equiv -4 \pmod{17}$ and $17 \mid 10^{2n}+1$, which gives the decomposition

$$10^{2n}+1 = [\tfrac1{17}(15\cdot 10^{n}-8)]^2 + [\tfrac1{17}(8\cdot 10^n +15 )]^2.$$

Here, $B = \tfrac1{17}(8\cdot 10^n + 15)$ so we may take $y = \tfrac4{17}(10^n+4)$.  Similarly, $x = \tfrac4{17}(4\cdot 10^n-1)$.  Taking $k=0$ this gives

$$ \color{red}{941176470588}^2 + \color{blue}{235294117648}^2 = \color{red}{941176470588}\color{blue}{235294117648}.$$

I don't see a strong connection to Pell equations but it certainly is possible when working with conics like these.

Comment: ! first of all thank you so much for your reply. Can you find relation to Pell equation or conics.

Comment: @Naroza_lary_sai $x^2 + y^2 = 10^n x + y $ is *already* a conic.

Comment: ! you are correct! can you think about pells eqation sir

Comment: I think Pell is useful only when the conic is a hyperbola. Here it seems by the above to be actually a circle, or at least an ellipse, so that Pell looks to be of unlikely use.

Comment: @coffeemath! discuss the relation of these equations with reduced ellipse form.

Comment: @Erick Wong!discuss the relation of these equations with reduced ellipse form.

Comment: @Naroza_lary_sai  In another question "xy is a square in this particular logic", you asked about $\bar{x}\bar{y}$ being a square, and in the answer you accepted, the relation to pell is fully explained. But that question is completely different from the one in this post, which is for $x^2+y^2=\bar{x}\bar{y}$, which leads to a circle equation as in Eric Wong's answer, for which pell is not relevant.