# Fermat primes and the equation $x^2+y^2 = 10^n x+y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is related to the [question by Naroza](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389700/) which was [ably answered by E. Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/389752/). In a nutshell, it seeks to find more examples of the curiosities,

$$12^2+33^2 = 1233$$

$$88^2+33^2 = 8833$$

or, in general, to solve,

$$x^2+y^2 = 10^n x+y$$

for **integer** $x,y$ (naturally, with size constraints on $x,y$). Wong gave,

$$a=4,\;\;b=10^{4m},\;\;x = \tfrac{a}{17}(ab-1),\;\;y = \tfrac{a}{17}(a+b)\tag{1}$$

where $m=4k+3$. For example, for $k=0$, we get,

$$ \color{red}{941176470588}^2 + \color{blue}{235294117648}^2 = \color{red}{941176470588}\color{blue}{235294117648}$$

and its partner as,

$$ {\color{red}{588}\color{blue}{2352}\color{red}{9412}}^2 + \color{blue}{235294117648}^2 = \color{red}{588}\color{blue}{2352}\color{red}{9412}\color{blue}{235294117648}$$

Note that,

$$ \color{red}{588}^2 + \color{blue}{2352}^2 = \color{red}{588}\color{blue}{2352}$$

$$ \color{red}{9412}^2 + \color{blue}{2352}^2 = \color{red}{9412}\color{blue}{2352}$$

Anyway, I noticed the *Fermat prime* 17 and, after a little experimentation, found,

$$a=16,\;\;b=10^{64m},\;\;x = \tfrac{a}{257}(ab-1),\;\;y = \tfrac{a}{257}(a+b)\tag{2}$$

$$a=256,\;\;b=10^{16384m},\;\;x = \tfrac{a}{65537}(ab-1),\;\;y = \tfrac{a}{65537}(a+b)\tag{3}$$

***Question***: Are the $x,y$ of (2), (3) also integers for *all* positive integer $m=4k+3$?

(I've tested it for the first few $k$ and it is true. Other *Fermat numbers* don't work. It seems the divisor must be prime > 5.)

Comment: Funny question, I like it. I don't know if I can answer though.

Comment: I normally pay little attention to properties that depend on our decimal system. But the fact that this system just so happen to have a Fermat prime may be related to this question.

Comment: What question?... What system? You're being a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the first one,

$\frac{a}{257}(ab-1)$ is an integer, if and only if

$(a^2+1)|(a^2b-a)=a(ab-1)$, if and only if

$(a^2+1)|ab-1$ (since $a,a^2+1$ are relatively prime), if and only if

$ab\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), since $a^2+1$ is prime in this case, $10^{a^2}=10^{256}\equiv 1\pmod{257}$.

Hence, $ab(10^{256})\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$.  Set $c=b10^{256}=10^{64(4k+3)}10^{256}=10^{64(4(k+1)+3)}$.  This can be repeated, to get $10^{64(4(k+2)+3)}$, etc, hence any $m=4k+3$.

Comment: Why does the conjecture hold if $10^{64 \times 4} \equiv 1 \pmod{a^2+1}$? I really don't see it. There's no power of two in there, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @vadim123: Before I accept your answer, it seems it needs some clarification. 1) I understand your point that $x$ is an integer iff $ab\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$ and Fermat's little theorem as, $q^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ where $p$ is a prime. But since the product of $a=16$ and $b=10^{64m}$ is ONLY a 4th power $ab = (2\cdot 10^{16m})^4$, where did you get the congruence $10^{256}\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$? 2) And can you clarify how Fermat's little theorem can apply to the second variable $y$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, if $c\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$, then $a(bc)\equiv 1\pmod{a^2+1}$.  Now follow my chain of implications back up, with $b$ replaced by $(bc)$.

Comment: Ok, I get that for $x$. Can you kindly sketch a proof for $y$ as well?